# Default domain with randomly redirect to multiple domains

Tags: nginx, apache2, nginx-config

I'm using Nginx for reverse proxy. I'm thinking something is it possible to redirect to random domains. For example, I have several domains 
mydomain.com 
mydomain1.com 
mydomain2.com 
mydomain3.com 
All domains are pointed to the same site which is hosted on one server. Is it possible when I request my default domain mydomain.com to choose randomly and redirect to one domain from the pool? I tried with rewrite rules, upstream balancing module also maps config with default domain and FastCGI or Lua to execute a shell script with random output string from an array. But no success.

Thanks! :)